# Real time updating of Javascript Calculator answer

Tags: javascript, onclick, calculator

Is there a way to get a javascript calculator to calculate an answer as a user types instead of having to press a "calculate" button like in this example?

```
<form  name="form" id="form">
<input type="Text" name="weight" size="4"> Weight (in Kilos)  
<input type="Text" name="height" size="4"> Height (in Centimeters)<br>
<input type="Text" name="BodyMassIndex" id="BodyMassIndex" size="4"> BMI     
<input type="button" style="font-size: 8pt" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateBMI()" name="button">
</form>
```

Using onblur is an improvement but you still have to click out of the text box to blur the input to get the answer. Like I say, I'd prefer the answer to update in real time. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is typing, you can use the `keyup` event.  So basically, everytime the user types a key, your event handler fires and can update the view/display.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onkeyup`.

e.g.

```
<form  name="form" id="form">
<input type="Text" name="weight" size="4" onkeyup="calculateBMI()"> Weight (in Kilos)  
<input type="Text" name="height" size="4" onkeyup="calculateBMI()"> Height (in Centimeters)<br>
<input type="Text" name="BodyMassIndex" id="BodyMassIndex" size="4"> BMI     
<input type="button" style="font-size: 8pt" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateBMI()" name="button">
</form>
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/VkCgh/).

**EDIT:** Changed to `onkeyup` after finding `onkeypress` didn't work for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<form  name="form" id="form">
    <input class="bmi_input" type="Text" name="weight" size="4"/> Weight (in Kilos)  
    <input class="bmi_input" type="Text" name="height" size="4"/> Height (in Centimeters)
    <input class="bmi_input" type="Text" name="BodyMassIndex" id="BodyMassIndex" size="4"/> BMI
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function calculateBMI() {
    console.log("I'm here");
}

var els = document.getElementsByClassName("bmi_input");
var sz = els.length;

for(var n = 0; n < sz; ++n) {
    els[n].onkeyup = calculateBMI;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/94hxS/

Comment: Thanks for this, just noticed a missing " on the third line after bmi_input

Comment: Woops.. Damn forgiving Chrome ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the [onChange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event in each of the input text boxes, calling your calculate function:

```
<form  name="form" id="form">
  <input type="Text" name="weight" size="4" onChange="calculateBMI()"> Weight (in Kilos)  
  <input type="Text" name="height" size="4" onChange="calculateBMI()"> Height (in Centimeters)<br>
  <input type="Text" name="BodyMassIndex" id="BodyMassIndex" size="4"> BMI     
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've found onChange only works after bluring in safari.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of two user text inputs, which "instantly" calculate the answer based on the called JavaScript function (The functions are also included). In addition, this code provides the option to also use a button (it is currently commented out). Hope this helps!

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="form-main">
    <div id="form-div">
      <form class="form" id="form1" method="post">

  <p class="celcius"><h2 style="color:#FFF">Input:</h2>
    <input name="celsius" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Temperature (Celsius)" onkeyup="Conversion()" id="celsius" />
  </p>

  <hr>
  <h2 style="color:#FFF">Result:</h2>

  <p class="fahrenheit">
    <input name="fahrenheit" type="text" class="feedback-input" id="fahrenheit" onkeyup="Conversion2()" placeholder="Temperature (Fahrenheit)" />
  </p>      

  <!--
  <div class="submit">
    <input type="button" value="CONVERT" id="button-blue" onClick="Conversion()"/>
    <div class="ease"></div>
  </div>
  -->
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function Conversion() {
    var tempCels = parseFloat(document.getElementById('celsius').value);
    tempFarh =(tempCels)*(1.8)+(32);
    document.getElementById('fahrenheit').value= tempFarh;
 }

function Conversion2() {
    var tempFarh = parseFloat(document.getElementById('fahrenheit').value);
    tempCels =(tempFarh - 32)/(1.8);
    document.getElementById('celsius').value= tempCels;
 }
```